# Barternura in English Online

Tags: internet, translation, mishna

We have a few English translations of Barternura at sefaria. Is there any site that offers a full English translation of Barternura's commentary of Mishnayot online?

Comment: Note there is an app with Kehati's translation, in English and Hebrew. Often more accessible than Bartenura. Exists for [iOS](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/kehati/id1059791961) and [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nocker.kehati&hl=en)

Comment: I need the barternura one specifically. I already have kehati app

Answer (score -1):

eMishna.com has an integrated English translation of Bartenura in the Mishnah translation
https://www.emishnah.com/

Comment: I need a full translatio